# Python logging how to track hostname in logs?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am using Python logging in this manner:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
logger.info("Some text.")
```

I have a bunch of IoT devices all running (making logs).  They stream their log data to a database.  To differentiate the source, I need to include the source IP address.

Is there a way to get hostname using logging?  Is IP Address or hostname tracked/trackable in LogRecords?

In general, what is the best way to add in hostname to a LogRecord?

Comment: They're adding a custom filter. That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import logging
from logging import Formatter
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
from socket import gethostname

hostname = socket.gethostname()
syslog = SysLogHandler(('my.logging.domain', 601))
syslog.setFormatter(
    Formatter(
        '{asctime} %s {name}: {levelname:8} {message}' % hostname,
        datefmt='%b %d %H:%M:%S',
        style='{'
    )
)

logger = logging.getLogger('myident')
logger.addHandler(syslog)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info('Hello, world!')
```

Based on [1](https://www.papertrail.com/help/configuring-centralized-logging-from-python-apps/#examples) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55584223/3787516) but skipping the filter/dynamic hostname. Tested with Python 3.9.15 and Papertrail.

Answer (score 13):

You can do that by adding a custom log filter and formatter that puts the host name in the log messages.

```
import logging, platform

class HostnameFilter(logging.Filter):
    hostname = platform.node()

    def filter(self, record):
        record.hostname = HostnameFilter.hostname
        return True

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.addFilter(HostnameFilter())
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(hostname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%b %d %H:%M:%S'))

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('Hello, world!')
```

Comment: Where do I get the `hostname` from to put into the formatter?

Comment: You don't. The logging module will automatically inject it into your logs. Same with time and other fields.

Comment: Check out the docs for the log record object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord

Comment: Check out this blog for an example https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-python-apps/#examples

Comment: It seems in the blog they use the external module `socket.gethostname()`, and in the LogRecord docs they manually type out `192.168.0.1`.  So basically, I have to get hostname from an external source

Comment: It looks like @gobernador had edited the question months later and updated it to include an actual hostname

Answer (score 7):

A simpler solution would be to pre-populate the format line with the hostname. For example:

```py
logging.basicConfig(
   #... your logging configuration,
   format="%(asctime)s {} %(message)s".format(socket.gethostname())
)
```

would generate a format line like

```
"%(asctime)s some-hostname %(message)s"
```

The drawback is that if the host name changes you'd need to restart your service/application. This is usually not a problem for most applications, especially if running on docker/k8s